# How to round a mesh?

Tags: mesh

I have objects in Blender, with a limited amount of faces. Several of the objects have rounded parts (like on the screenshot below). When rendering this - even with smooth shading - the "rounded" parts look blocky. I would like them the be nicely curved. Obviously I could manually model some more faces. Given the large amount of objects, that's a lot of work. So I'd like to find an automated way.

I already tried the smooth modifier as well as subsurf (--> too much deformation). Nothing works.

Would anybody know how this could be achieved with e.g. a bit of Python code or so? I have a lot of Python experience, so integrating some Python source is no issue if that can provide a solution.

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: If objects you'd like to be rounded all are the same like on the screenshot, then you can duplicate and arrange them across the scene after tweaking mesh. If objects are absolutely different (how exactly, if they are / aren't?), then it's not clear how this could be automated.

Comment: Could you show what it looks like when rendered, and could you also upload a .blend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to deal with this is to help out the subsurface modifier do its job. You can, for example

- Mark your desired hard edges as creases prior to using the subsurf modifier.

Or

- You can just create edge loops near your curves to control how sharp they should be, so that subsurf doesn't oversmooth them.

See this youtube video "Tutorial: Sharp Edges on Smooth Objects"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgzmSnQt0bQ

I'm not a Blender expert in any way, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Defining creases does indeed provide a solution. The subsurf still results in deformation of the mesh, but that is due to this mesh originally being one with triangles converted to quads via "mesh | tris to quads". If I could find a way around that issue, the solution would be complete.

Comment: @Sven again, my experience with blender is not huge, but I see people retopologizing the mesh by hand a lot. a fully automated way interests me as well

Answer (score 0):

You could try selecting the faces you want to be rounded in edit mode, then press 'P' then 'by selection', then try subsurf on this new separate mesh, although you may then have to join up the vertices from the other part of the object.

Maybe add the blend file so people can see the object better?